# Java OOPS example java virtual machine flow

Tags: java, oop

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h=new Hello();

        System.out.println(h.a);
    }
}

class Hello{
     int a;//even i add static modifier it gives the same result
     a=10;
}
```

cheaked exception

`a=10` -> identifier expected

i want to  kno the reason this error by internal functioning of jvm

Comment: @TheLostMind The compiler is *printing* this error. Exceptions are thrown; compilation errors are printed.

Comment: @EJP - Yes. I should have worded it correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the JVM itself but with the Java language specifications. This is not valid Java.

To fix it, you can assign the value when declaring the variable:

```
class Hello{
     int a=10;
}
```

You can also use an initialisation block...

```
class Hello{
     int a;
     {a=10;}
}
```

...or put this in the constructor

```
class Hello{
     int a;
     public Hello{a=10;}
}
```

Note that you also need to change the `main` method because it is `static`

```
Hello h = new Test().new Hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this:
**int a = 10;**
Otherwise you have to wrap the assignment within a method and/or the constructor. You cannot actually write codes directly in the class definition. You can only declared instance and class variables, constructors and methods.
Also in this case is not the Virtual Machine that throws the exception, the code simply won't compile.